# Get req.body in two different ways

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have one question/problem with request in `put` method
if I use this code:

```
    userFactory.editProduct = function(id) {
    return $http.put('/api/editProduct', id)
}
```

and

```
    router.put('/editProduct', function(req, res){
    var editProduct = req.body._id;
})
```

I get properly req.body._id
but if I use this code:

```
    userFactory.deleteDescription = function(id) {
    return $http.put('/api/editProduct/' + id)
}
```

and

```
    router.put('/editProduct/:id', function(req, res){
    var editProduct = req.body._id;
})
```

I get empty `{}`. could you explain/help me what I should do in second case to get properly `_id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At second case, the id is not a body parameter but it's a URL route parameter.

So try accessing the id as;

```
req.params.id
```